# curl_easy_perform return CURLE_WRITE_ERROR, but I won't write nothing

Tags: c++, iphone, ios, curl, ios6

I wrote this simple code to check network connection or our iOS apps:

```
int CL_Network::checkConnectionInt1(){

  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;
  curl = curl_easy_init();

  if (curl) {

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.google.com");

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    return res;

  }

  curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  return -1;

}
```

Our test are ok, return 0 when Wi-Fi enabled, but Apple reviewer return 23 (CURL_WRITE_ERROR) with Wi-Fi enable or disable.

The reviewer tells us others strange behaviors (considering Wi-Fi enabled)

- iPod touch with iOS 5.1 returns 0, with same Wi-Fi where iPhone5 with iOS 6.3 returns 23
- iPhone 5 with iOS 6.3 run step by step debug returns 0 (I don't know if it is happened only one time or always)

**Have you any suggestions?**

Last note, verbose output of curl_easy_perform

> - About to connect() to www.google.com port 80 (#0)
> - Trying 173.194.35.20...
> - connected
> - Connected to www.google.com (173.194.35.20) port 80 (#0)
>
> > GET / HTTP/1.1 Host: www.google.com Accept: */*
> >     
> >     < HTTP/1.1 302 Found < Location: http://www.google.it/ <
> >     Cache-Control: private < Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 <
> >     Set-Cookie:
> >     PREF=ID=08f8ea131f5d39dd:FF=0:TM=1367680782:LM=1367680782:S=at5IyKNTpeoFFnif; expires=Mon, 04-May-2015 15:19:42 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com <
> >     Set-Cookie:
> >     NID=67=uPKHTXNtVuYy4QOwVHstK4NzMGZcDssYW.....;
> >     expires=Sun, 03-Nov-2013 15:19:42 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com;
> >     HttpOnly < P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See
> >     http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151657
> >     for more info." < Date: Sat, 04 May 2013 15:19:42 GMT < Server: gws <
> >     Content-Length: 218 < X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block <
> >     X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN <  
> >     302 Moved
> >
> > ## 302 Moved
> >
> > The document
> >     has moved [here](http://www.google.it/). 
> >     * Connection #0 to host www.google.com left intact
> >     * Closing connection #0 2013-05-04 17:19:42.183 
> >     testcurl[1468:c07] checkConnection 1: 0

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a writecallback as well

```
size_t CurlWriteCallback(char* buf, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* up)
{ 
    TRACE("CURL - Response received:\n%s", buf);
    TRACE("CURL - Response handled %d bytes:\n%s", size*nmemb);

    // tell curl how many bytes we handled
    return size*nmemb;
}

// ...



int CL_Network::checkConnectionInt1(){

  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;
  curl = curl_easy_init();

  if (curl) {

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &CurlWriteCallback);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.google.com");

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    return res;

  }

  curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  return -1;

}
```